# How to encrypt data in hdfs , and then create hive or impala table to query it?

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hive, hdfs, impala

Recently, I came accross a situation:
There is a data file in remote hdfs, we need to encrpt the data file and then create impala table to query the data in local hdfs system, how impala query encryped data file, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I could not control the query sql by create udf function ,since the query sql is not visible. I could only have control to create table.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by creating User Defined Functions(UDF) in hive. You can create UDF functions by using UDF Hive interface. Then, make jar out of your UDF class, put hive lib.

Comment: I could not control the query sql by udf ,since the query sql is not visible, is there other way ?

Comment: I think this is link explains well about how to create UDF. `http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/08/10/guide-to-writing-hive-udfs.html`

Comment: You are encrypted your data that in hdfs, aren't you? Then, I assume it is not encrypted yet. So, you can do encryption in two ways.

Comment: One way is that, you can create tempory hive table, and then put the UDF jar into hive lib path, then use that UDF function to encrypt your data to your real hive table. Another way is that, if you know Spark, you can implement an encyrption  algorithm do to that.

Comment: I think the current problem is not about how to encrypt the data. I'd like to clear the problem, we have a app based on impala table, but the data is not allowed to put in our local env, we have to access the data in remote hdfs, now we want to deal with how to use local impala table access remote hdfs data under the security. The query sql it not visible, we could only create local impala table to map with the remote data.

Comment: impala deamons can be authorized by enabling ` -server_name` and `-authorization_policy_file` options on all nodes, and setting up the Kerberos for authentication.  Another point, if you don't want to see the data you can mask it.